# Chromedriver in jar does not exist

Tags: java, selenium

I exported a java project with chromedriver.exe in the resource folder. Using the code below I am able to run the project successfully.

```
public static void setUp(){
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/test/resources/test/chromedriver.exe");

    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

After exporting the project as a Jar file I can see that the driver was exported in the jar but I am still getting this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\Users\user\Desktop\resources\test\chromedriver.exe

Comment: Isn't the error clear that the program is looking for the _chromedriver_ binary within `C:\Users\user\Desktop\resources\test\ ` sub-directory ?

Comment: Yes that's my problem, the program is looking at C:\User\user and not within the jar itself. I don't know how to tell it to look in the jar file

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.getProperty("user.dir")` to get file location.

Try below code :-

```
 public static void setUp(){

    String path= System.getProperty("user.dir");

       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", path+"\\src\\test\\resources\\test\\chromedriver.exe");

        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

  }
```